# MySQL inserting date value from the next row

Tags: mysql

Good day guys i would like to ask for another help.
im using MySQL, i would like to update the column nextdate from the column add_date of the next row.

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| percode |  add_date  | nextdate | 
+---------+------------+----------+
|       1 | 2017-01-20 |          |         
|       1 | 2017-02-01 |          |          
|       1 | 2017-03-15 |          |          
|       1 | 2017-04-09 |          |         
|       2 | 2017-01-26 |          |          
|       2 | 2017-02-05 |          |          
|       2 | 2017-02-28 |          |          
|       3 | 2017-01-26 |          |               
+---------+------------+----------+
```

as you can see on the 2nd column, the add_date of the next row is now updated and now contains the value of the column add_date from the next row as long as they have the same percode, and if it encounter the last row it will put the current date as nextdate.

```
 +---------+------------+----------+
 | percode |  add_date  | nextdate | 
 +---------+------------+----------+
 |       1 | 2017-01-20 |2017-02-01|          
 |       1 | 2017-02-01 |2017-03-15|          
 |       1 | 2017-03-15 |2017-04-09|         
 |       1 | 2017-04-09 |2018-10-12|          
 |       2 | 2017-01-26 |2017-02-05|         
 |       2 | 2017-02-05 |2017-02-28|          
 |       2 | 2017-02-28 |2018-10-12|          
 |       3 | 2017-01-26 |2018-10-12|          
 +---------+------------+----------+
```

is there any way this could work by just using MySQL queries?

Comment: Seems like a flawed logic in your application if you have to resort to this sort of "hack". Why are you having redundant data in the first place?

Comment: Given that rows in SQL tables represent unordered sets, define 'next'

Comment: next = same "percode" but chronologically higher than the previous "add_date"